# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in flutter http request

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I am trying to fetch all the data from the api using flutter http package. I am getting an error

"type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'"

Here is the link where I am trying to fetch data from

```
https://wrestlingworld.co/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/128354
```

Here is my model

```
class NewsModel {
  int? id;
  String? date;
  String? slug;
  String? status;
  Title? title;
  Title? content;
  List<OgImage>? ogImage;
  String? author;

  NewsModel(
      {this.id,
        this.date,
        this.slug,
        this.status,
        this.title,
        this.content,
        this.ogImage,
        this.author});

  NewsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    date = json['date'];
    slug = json['slug'];
    status = json['status'];
    title = json['title'] != null ? new Title.fromJson(json['title']) : null;
    content =
    json['content'] != null ? new Title.fromJson(json['content']) : null;
    if (json['og_image'] != null) {
      ogImage = <OgImage>[];
      json['og_image'].forEach((v) {
        ogImage!.add(new OgImage.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    author = json['author'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['date'] = this.date;
    data['slug'] = this.slug;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.title != null) {
      data['title'] = this.title!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.content != null) {
      data['content'] = this.content!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.ogImage != null) {
      data['og_image'] = this.ogImage!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['author'] = this.author;
    return data;
  }
}

class Title {
  String? rendered;

  Title({this.rendered});

  Title.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    rendered = json['rendered'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['rendered'] = this.rendered;
    return data;
  }
}

class OgImage {
  String? url;

  OgImage({this.url});

  OgImage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:wrestling_news_app/Model/NewsModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class NewsController with ChangeNotifier{
  String urlnews = "https://wrestlingworld.co/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=22";
  List<NewsModel> _news = [];

  Future<bool> getNews() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(urlnews);
    // var token = storage.getItem('token');
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      print(response.body);
      var data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      // print(data);
      List<NewsModel> temp = [];
      data.forEach((element) {
        NewsModel product = NewsModel.fromJson(element);
        temp.add(product);
      });
      _news = temp;
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
  List<NewsModel> get allNews {
    return [..._news];
  }

  NewsModel getEventDetails(int id){
    return _news.firstWhere((element) => element.id == id);
  }


}
```

Here is the code where I tried to output the code:

```
   Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: allNews.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: NewsCard(
                              title: allNews[i].title!.rendered!,
                          desciption: allNews[i].content!.rendered!,
                          ),

                        );
                      }),)
```

Previously I tried to fetch using FuturreBuilder. But With future builder I couldnt fetch the details. for that reason I am using this method to fetch data from the api. Can you please answer me what is wrong with my code?

Here is my api response

```
[{"id":128640,"date":"2022-11-04T15:09:58","date_gmt":"2022-11-04T09:39:58","guid":{"rendered":"https:\/\/wrestlingworld.co\/?p=128640"},"modified":"2022-11-04T15:10:04","modified_gmt":"2022-11-04T09:40:04","slug":"impact-knockouts-tag-team-championship-match-announced-for-over-drive-2022","status":"publish","type":"post","link":"https:\/\/wrestlingworld.co\/news\/impact-knockouts-tag-team-championship-match-announced-for-over-drive-2022","title":{"rendered":"Impact Knockouts Tag Team Championship Match Announced for Over Drive"},"content":{"rendered":"\n<p>Impact Knockouts Tag Team Championships will be on the line at Over Drive on November 18th. It has <a href=\"https:\/\/impactwrestling.com\/2022\/11\/03\/tasha-steelz-savannah-evans-look-to-topple-the-death-dollz-in-knockouts-world-tag-team-title-showdown-at-over-drive\/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer noopener nofollow\">been announced<\/a> that Death Dollz (Taya Valkyrie and Jessicka) will be defending their titles against Tasha Steelz and Savannah
I/flutter (12372): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
```

Comment: can you include your api response too?

Comment: try `int.parse();` [refer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/parse.html)

Comment: I am getting 200 status from api call. @eamirho3ein

Comment: Where should I include the code you wrote? @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: @sakibOvi I ask for api response not api status code.

Comment: Ok I am sharing it. @eamirho3ein

Comment: convert NewsModel id type Int? to var type

Comment: Stackoverflow is not letting me share the respons. @eamirho3ein

Comment: @SachinKumawat still same

Comment: you can edit your question and include response

Comment: Use a try/catch in your fromJson method to identify the value in error.

Comment: @SachinKumawat I did. please check

Comment: @eamirho3ein please check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change  `String? author` to `int? author`. I see api return "author": 6 type is int.

Answer (score -2):

**final Author : 6;
Error Causer**

This Issue  Is you are Getting the Author as Int From The Api you given the type as String? In The Model If You Change The Type To Int The Problem gets Resolved

Comment: I changed the Id type to String still same

Comment: Edited Please Do check Now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).